# mvc .net mobile: how to go about arranging the controllers (very beginner)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

So I want to start working on specific pages on my website to have a mobile version. I was wondering how I should go about it? Do I create a new controller for each controller so that if it detects mobile then it redirects to that controller? or do i just use css to change how the page gets viewed?

If I need to create a new controlelr do I host it on a subdomain?

Comments are greatly appreciated.

Thanks!!

Comment: You probably should invest in a good tutorial book. Because stackoverflow is for problems or specific questions, not tutorials. That is why you are getting downvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@TheRealKingK is right about picking up some books on the matter. There are always 1000 ways to solve a problem, so it really depends on the variables involved in your project. I read an article in the latest MSDN that touches on mobile/desktop strategies and it had some good insight.

1. CSS media queries are excellent for helping render things for different sized screen, but do not help with detecting hardware capabilities, or filtering out heavy media out of the site for faster downloads on say a 3G mobile network.
2. Having a seperate controller base could be a decent strategy. I would have ALL your controller inherit from a custom base controller that (among other things), would determine where the request is coming from, and route them to the right controller. This really depending on what the site is for and what your client needs on the desktop versus a mobile app (native or HTML5)

I am playing around with rolling an MVC4 blogging application with a custom content management on the backend. Thus far it is pretty lightweight, so CSS is working for me.

I dunno if this sounds like a nerd-rambling or not, but hopefully it gives you some insight.

Comment: I actually just read about a cool thing MVC has built in (Not sure if just MVC4 or 3 as well). But lets say we have a HomeController. For the Home views, you can have index.cshtml, AND index.mobile.cshtml, and depending on where the request comes from it will render each page according. Not sure the mechanics involved, but may be worth checking out.

Comment: oh awesome! im using .aspx engine though. ill look around.. thanks again!